# What happened to Dee's motorcycle?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

I can't figure this out. Season 7, Episode 3.  Dee goes out on a motorcycle after getting a radio message about a "smash and grab".  Negan tells him to let Fat Joe take care of it, but Dee insists he'll take care of it.

He rides up to an underpass. Sees a bunch of walkers all ground into the pavement. He's walking his bike through it, and suddenly a walker falls off the bridge and lands next to the bike. Dee struggles with the walker and eventually shoots it in the head.

The next time we see Dee, he's walking his bike with a flat tire, a bent rim and busted spokes.

What happened to the bike?  Was that supposedly the damage from simply letting it fall over??

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a way to illustrate his escalating effort and hardships to reach his target.

There might be some hidden meaning, since it made each time less sense to keep pushing the bike. It was not working bike on 1st scene (why not stash/hide or abandon it?). Busted up bike in 2nd scene (why still push it?). No bike on the last scene (why abandon it now?). But if there is something to be read there, it's conveyed very poorly IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's not entirely clear what happened to the bike.  However, there were a couple of other walkers that fell off the overpass while Dee was struggling with the first (primarily observed as audible "thumps" since the camera was focused up close on Dee.)  I inferred that they fell on top of the bike and caused the damage to the wheel and such.

As for why he eventually abandoned the bike, I think he dropped it when he caught up to the guy he was chasing (couldn't very easily stop the guy while dragging a busted up motorcycle.)  IIRC, Dee also told that guy to pick up the bike after Dee was holding him at gunpoint, but the other guy refused to do so.

Once again, I agree this sequence of events was not very clearly described in the episode.

Answer (score 1):

There was a chase scene that preceded the wrecked motorcycle that was edited out for whatever reason. The bike and Dee wrecked while chasing the man who ran away, who had gained access to a vehicle somehow.

Comment: Got a source for this?